# Get responses form a specific Google Form PHP / Laravel

Tags: laravel, google-api, google-forms

I try to access to a Google Form but the API is in Google Apps Scripts. So we can't access it with a PHP script.
I'm using Laravel and this package could do the job but it's not compatible anymore :

https://github.com/akaramires/laravel-googleforms

How can I execute a Google Apps Script to get responses (with files uploaded by user) in a specific Google Form ?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response

Any ideas ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways that you could do this:

1. Consider deploying the Script as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). In particular, have a look at the section **Deploying a script as a web app**. Deploying scripts in this way allows you to do GET or POST requests to execute the code inside Google Scripts on demand.
2. Look at using the [App Scripts API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/). I've previously used this API to build multiple Google Forms rather than building each one manually.